# nginx の裏にある websocket サーバーに対する、 nginx の設定は？

Tags: nginx, websocket

とあるリモートのサーバー上で動いている websocket サーバープログラムに対して、そのサーバー上の nginx からリバースプロキシをはる際に、何も考えずに upstream 指定しただけでは、 websocket はうまく動作しないことに気づきました。

#### 質問

- nginx で websocket をリバースプロキシする際に必要な設定は何ですか？

Answer (score 1):

`Upgrade`ヘッダを指定する必要があるようです。

参考: [WebSocket proxying](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html)

上記ページ抜粋:

```
location /chat/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```